# Search if any element of array found in another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

How can I search an element of an array in another array? If any element is found, the search function returns true, else it returns false.

For example:

```
$mainArray = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$tosearch = array(2,7); //returns true as 2 is in main array.
$tosearch = array(7,8); //return false as no element found in main array.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect) for that, like this:

```
if (array_intersect($mainArray, $tosearch)) {
    // elements in common
}
```

Comment: Thanks,, it work,, i didnt know that PHP got a builtin function for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
var_dump((bool) array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```

**EDIT**

Just to clarify my answer ... since you are looking for TRUE or FALSE, I include a boolean typecast `(bool)`. Without the cast, `array_intersect` will return a *truthy* array, but still an array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're working in PHP, or is your array syntax just for illustration?

In any case, look at the array_intersect() function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php